# Logcat output disappearing when toggling filters

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I've found that if from within Android Studio (v1.3) I toggle the filter setting for the logcat output between "Show only selected application" and "No filter" then after a few times the output disappears and I can never get it displayed again.

I also get the same sort of thing using the monitor tool instead of AS, suggesting its an issue with logcat.

These screenshots show what I mean (the filter term and matching results has been redacted but its the same term and is never changed).

1) After rebooting the device AS/Logcat is displaying the expected logging:
[image]

2) If I change the filter from "Show only selected application" to "No filters", there's now less output. Why is that?
[image]

3) Now if I set it back to "Show only selected application" its gone:
[image]

4) Switch back to "No filters" and its still gone:
[image]

If I now remove the search term then logcat shows the full output from the device except its missing all the output from my app.

Where's the output gone from logcat and is there anyway to get it back?

Comment: Is the log content disappearing after several minutes, or does all of the above occur within seconds? I think Android may recycle/clear its logs within 10 or 15 minutes, so that might be a factor.

Comment: also see the big red warning `no debuggle application` usually means you're doing it wrong

Comment: I agree with this question and upvote it, because I saw the same issue. Especially for example, when you do clear it sometimes it doesn't continue to log anything else or restores all the old logs. I think it is a bug for Android Studio

Comment: @LarsH its occurring within seconds, as soon as the toggling is done

Comment: @Blundell as I mentioned, I'm not running anything in Android Studio. AS is simply connected to the device via adb that is all. Hence logcat simply displays everything the device is spewing out

Comment: you said `its missing all the output from my app` , and I'm saying, behaviour is not guaranteed if your app is not in debug mode

Comment: I switched to use the monitor tool instead and got the same sort of results. So its nothing to do with Android Studio as such, a bug with logcat? I've edited the question to remove the specific reference to AS.

Comment: Did you enable adb integration in AS?

Comment: I think it's well known bug. Upgrade your android Studio to the latest one, specially Android Studio 2.0 in Canary Channell

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue for some time. Restarting the ADB has no effect and the only resolution I have found is to simply restart Android Studio.

Comment: But, as mentioned,it also happens to me when I'm not using android studio.